Define types for JSX: Property 'key' does not exist on type
I'm implementing an application customizing the jsxFactory function. So, my tsconfig.json is the following:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "createDOMElement"
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}

where createDOMElement is my custom function invoked for every JSX element.
My application code is the following:
function createDOMElement(tagName: string | Function, props: any, ...children: any[]) {
    /* my custom implementation */
}

function Button(data: { text: string }) {
    const button = (
        <button>{data.text}</button>
    );
    /* some logic here */
}

export function Main() {
    const el = (
        <Button text="the text" key="my-key"  />
    );

    /* some logic here */
}

As you can see, I defined two components:

Button is a component that accepts a string text as a property
Main is a component that creates the Button component, giving text and key properties.

While the text property is defined by Button signature, key isn't.
Conceptually, key shouldn't be allowed for the component Button. In fact, VSCode gives me an error:
Type '{ key: string; text: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ text: string; }'.
  Property 'key' does not exist on type '{ text: string; }'.ts(2322)

Anyway, some libraries like react allow the specification of the key property even if the component doesn't have it as a property, and I want to do the same for my custom implementation of jsxFactory.
If I understood correctly, this is a typescript type problem, and the JSX typescript namespace allows me to define it, but I didn't understand how to let the key property for every component.
I want to instantiate components specifying the defined properties and the key property, even if it is not specified.
How can I configure typescript to support it?

To support key attribute, you should extend IntrinsicAttributes interface as follows:

declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicAttributes {
            key?: string
        }
    }
}



Simply add the key prop explicitly for all Components in your createDOMElement JSX factory function signature, typically with an intersection:
function createDOMElement<P extends {}>(
  tagName: string | Function,
  props: P & { key?: string | number | bigint | null | undefined } | null,
  ...children: any[]
) {
    /* my custom implementation */
}

That is what React.createElement (which is the default for the "jsxFactory" compiler option in tsconfig.json) does, through the Attributes interface:
// #554
function createElement<P extends {}>(
  type: FunctionComponent<P> | ComponentClass<P> | string,
  props?: Attributes & P | null,
  ...children: ReactNode[]
): ReactElement<P>;

// #246
/**
 * @internal The props any component can receive.
 * You don't have to add this type. All components automatically accept these props.
 * ```tsx
 * const Component = () => <div />;
 * <Component key="one" />
 * ```
 * [...]
 */
interface Attributes {
  key?: Key | null | undefined;
}

// #239
/**
 * A value which uniquely identifies a node among items in an array.
 *
 * @see {@link https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key React Docs}
 */
type Key = string | number | bigint;


VSCode ignores the jsxFactory configuration. Anyway, I would like to thank you for the Attributes link in React. It allows me to inspect how React does it and provide the answer that works for me.
